# Cauchy-Riemann equation and differentiability in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that if the Cauchy-Riemann equation is fulfilled and if a complex function $f$ has continuous partial derivatives at a point, $f$ will be differentiable in $\mathbb{C}$.

However, suppose $f$'s domain is in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Does it follow that if $f$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation AND has continuous partial derivatives at a point, it is also differentiable over $\mathbb{C}$? Which would not be possible if only the latter condition is fulfilled.

Comment: You need to distinguish between $\mathbb{C}$- and $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable. For $\mathbb{R}$-differentiability, existence and continuity of the partial derivatives is enough.

Comment: If the function's domain is $\Bbb R^2$ then what do you mean by "differentiable over $\Bbb C$"? If you mean "let's interpret $\Bbb R^2$ as $\Bbb C$" then of course: you're right back where you started, with the Cauchy-Riemann equations being fulfilled by a complex function.

Comment: I do not see what the question is, since the second paragraph restates the first.